# Force ngRepeated element to redraw after filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I need to redraw rows after filtering `ngRepeat`-ed array with "search" like  filter, in order to highlight the "needle".

I wrote a filter function for the parsed text, but it does not fire once the filtering (the search like one) is done.

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in collection | orderBy:sortExp:sortReverse | filter:multiFilter()">
  <td ng-repeat="(prop,value) in transaction" title="{{prop}}">
    {{value | filter:highlightNeedle(prop)}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm assuming Angular is not redrawing these rows in order to save performance, but that is preventing me from implementing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add you javascript ? The controller and the highlightNeedle thing ?

Just considering the name of you filter, i think you're not using it for what's it's been made for.

If you want to hightlight your cell you should put use something like ng-class or ng-style. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

A example would be to have a css class "myClass" doing the highlighting stuff and add to your 
    ng-class="{myClass:check(prop)}"

where "check" is a function declared in the scope returning true/false.

Note that if your table is really big, you may have some trouble because angular will watch for change and create scope for every {{}}.

Comment: I probably poorly explained the feature im trying to achieve. I want to split the string into three `span` element, only one of which will have a special class. I dont need much help with the element manipulation but with the fact that my filter is not applied, when other rows are removed. Am I making any sense ?